# data table ifelse taking along time

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data table with 12M rows and for 1 columns I would like to modify the TYPE field. First I make it a character then I modify the text.

The second operation takes 6 seconds which is how long the data frame version takes

here is the data frame version:

```
df$TYPE = as.character(df$TYPE)
df$TYPE = ifelse( is.na(df$TYPE )== TRUE, "NONE", df$TYPE)


here is the data table code that takes just as long as the code above:

dt[, TYPE := as.character(TYPE) ]
   dt[, TYPE := ifelse( is.na(TYPE )== TRUE, "NONE", TYPE)]
```

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Use `dt[is.na(TYPE), TYPE := "NONE"]` not `ifelse`.

Comment: the column needs to be made a character column first. that wont work

Comment: I was referring to your final line of code. You can keep the conversion to character as-is... I don't think it can be sped up ... depends what the class of the column is to begin with / why it isn't a character already.